# PHP include within include not working

Tags: php, include

I have the following setup:

index.php (in root) is including results.php (also in root)

```
<?php include("results.php"); ?>
```

Within results, I'm including another file using the URI (which I set with a variable) to get the correct directory, since I'm using rewrites to make the "results page" different depending on user input.

So, inside results.php:

```
<?php include($website['uri'] . 'elements/keywords.php'); ?>
```

For reference, when I try to make the above a link, it goes through.

```
<a href="<?php echo $website['uri']."elements/keywords.php"; ?>">Test</a>
```

I can click the link and there is no problem, but absolutely nothing happens when I try to include it. My results.php is included inside index.php just fine.

Can anybody offer some tips to get this working?

UPDATE: $website['uri'] is set and is ALWAYS "/seo-project/", which is the directory I'm working inside (where index.php is). Replacing the variable with the relative path does nothing but still works with the link.

Comment: Don't use a URL use the file system path or relative paths.  Maybe just `elements/keywords.php`.

Comment: $website['uri'] is '/seo-project/', which is the directory I'm working in.

Replacing that variable doesn't help. It still shows up in the link and displays nothing inside the include.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use BASE URL, instead use Physical path. Remove the $website['uri'] part from the path